# Change or reassign object typing dynamically in typescript

Tags: typescript

Here is the example you can paste in typescript playground:

```
class Greeter {
greeting: {};
constructor(message: string) {
    let newTyping: { text: string }; // reassign needed
    this.greeting=newTyping
    this.greeting.text = message; // typing error
}
greet() {
    return "Hello, " + this.greeting.text;
 }
}

let greeter = new Greeter("world");

let button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = "Say Hello";
button.onclick = function() {
alert(greeter.greet());
}

document.body.appendChild(button);
```

As you can see, this.greeting.text shows an error: I need to reassign {} to {text:string} typing.

Is it possible to do this dynamically because in my code, I don't know which type will be used to populate the object at runtime (so I leave it as a default typing) ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You should redesign your code to always use the same type.

Comment: *in my code, I don't know which type will be used to populate the object at runtime* -- how do you mean? If you don't know the type then your code has several errors, because it assumes that `greeting` is an object with `text` property.

Comment: Just imagine a shared property object in a class: you don't know how others  will define this shared object, so they need to be able to apply their own typing and get their own intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

There's a special type in TS for that: `any`. It's much closer to "default type" then an empty object type (`{}`). The compiler uses it by default if there's no type information available for a symbol (variable, property).

Comment: But it makes your code weaker; you should never use it.

Comment: I don't. But author of the question needs it for some reason.

Comment: No; the author needs to make saner types.

Comment: "any" just avoid compiler error, but I need to redefine typing as SLaks told